# jquery addclass, removeclass and appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of a problem, I'm trying to work out a sort of options inside a div, that when clicked, appendTo another div, in case they get clicked again in the other div they will go back and so on... here is my code:

```
    $(".selectable").bind('click', function(){
        $(this).removeClass("selectable").addClass("unselectable").appendTo('#selectableQuitar');
    });

    $(".unselectable").bind('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("unselectable").addClass("selectable").appendTo('#selectableAgregar');  
  });
```

I tried plenty of ways around, when you click the first element it will change classes and appendTo the next div, exactly the other way around... the first click actually works but the second one not exactly, if you Inspect the Element it will show the new class but the click event will not trigger... any ideas?? just in case you need more info, the divs and elements inside:

```
<div id="pruebaSelectableAgregar">
<ol id="selectable" class="prueba">
  <li class="selectable">Item 1</li>
  <li class="selectable">Item 2</li>
  <li class="selectable">Item 3</li>
  <li class="selectable">Item 4</li>
  <li class="selectable">Item 5</li>
  <li class="selectable">Item 6</li>
</ol>
</div>

<div id="pruebaSelectableQuitar">
    <ol id="selectableQuitar">
        <li class="unselectable"> Prueba 1</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding and removing classes dynamically for elements which are registered with click events, you have to use `event delegation` in this situation.

Try,

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectable', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("selectable").addClass("unselectable").appendTo('#selectableQuitar');
});

$(document).on('click', '.unselectable', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("unselectable").addClass("selectable").appendTo('#selectableAgregar');  
});
```

Additionally, you can use `.toggleClass()` to simplify your code like,

```
.toggleClass("selectable unselectable")
```

Comment: Now I know where I went wrong... Event Delegation is new for me but google helped... still isn't working but I think I'm on the right path now (:

Comment: I'm getting Object #<Object> has no method 'on' error, already downloaded latest jquery library and googled a lot but can't find a good answer on this

Comment: @LuigiCordobaGranera Show me the code that you have tried.!

Comment: thanks again for your help! here is the script:

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  

$(document).on('click', '.selectable', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("selectable").addClass("unselectable").appendTo('#selectableQuitar');
});

$(document).on('click', '.unselectable', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("unselectable").addClass("selectable").appendTo('#selectableAgregar');  
});

});
  </script>

Comment: I just face these same problem again and your solution worked perfectly, thanks again man!